# Kerning with parentheses

Tags: kerning, parentheses

Given the MWE below, one can see that the spacing around the parentheses is rather awkward. The opening parenthesis is too close to `\cos` and `\sin`, and too far away from the `\omega`. The closing parenthesis is too far away from `\varphi`. Is there a way to reduce/add some kerning?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
$ \mathrm{e}^{\,\mathrm{j}(\omega t + \varphi)} =\cos (\omega t + \varphi) + \mathrm{j}\sin (\omega t + \varphi) $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: of cource one can use `\kern` to add kerning, but I'm looking for a more general way.

Comment: Of course there are many ways to do so. But I think the spacing is by design.

Comment: @JouleV  Correct, but I don't like it.

Comment: Are you looking for an automatic solution? The fact that you already used `\,` in the exponent makes me think that you know about the manual solution `\sin (\!\omega t + \varphi\!)` already. (You can pick different kerns than `\!` with `\mkern -2mu`, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374021/35864)

Comment: @moewe: Yes I was looking for an automatic solution. I used the thin space because the superscript j was too close to e. If one uses i as the imaginary unit, then no thin space is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to automatically add some extra kerning to a glyph in text mode, then I'd tell you to look into `microtype`'s `\SetExtraKerning` command. Unfortunately, that doesn't work in math mode. I think your best option is using the `\mkern` command made specifically to be used in math mode. Here's how it looks

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\newcommand{\leftpar}{\mkern3mu(\mkern-3mu}
\newcommand{\rightpar}{\mkern-3mu)\mkern3mu}
\begin{document}
$ \mathrm{e}^{\,\mathrm{j} \leftpar \omega t + \varphi \rightpar} =\cos \leftpar\omega t + \varphi\rightpar + \mathrm{j}\sin \leftpar\omega t + \varphi\rightpar $
\end{document}
```

Where `mu` stands for math units and it's defined as 1/18 of `em`.

[image]

Comment: I came to that same conclusion. It's definitily this font, no problems in lmodern.